# Jquery small animation error

Tags: jquery, animation, crash

I have created a small animation. There is an error though. Please take a look at this fiddle:

[Link to the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/renec112/CFx7k/2/#base)

Error on the headline aniamation. Hover the cat to trigger animation. While that, hover right over to the link that flys in . the h1 headline will crash and get stuck.

maybe its a selecttion error? it seems like the a href also triggers some elements. PLease help.

I might have explained it funny, but its hard to explain and hard to trick the bug. 
Try to hover the second picture. and go to the first. while the animation plays, try to hover right above the incomming link paragraph

Comment: is your goal to hide headline and show link when you hover?

Comment: i can't see problem, really (tested in firefox and chrome)

Comment: I tried it in chrome, safari and firefox... Works fine

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. Yes i am trying to hide the headline. It should go smoothly down to the bottom. Here is a video on dropbox to show the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/afyu0b8w61iqmnt/20140620_133844.mp4 First i try to find the bug. then hover as how i wan't it to work. at last a find the bug agian.. thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of your problem are animations interfering with each other.

Here's the code with .stop() method that stops the current animation (before starting a new one).

```
$(".gallery_container").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $('#color_overlay', this).stop().animate({ opacity:"0.7" }, {duration: 300, ease:     "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
    $('#sub_overskrift_container', this).stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, {duration: 300, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
    $('#paragraf_container', this).stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, {duration: 300, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
    $('#overskrift_container', this).stop().animate({ top: "300px" }, {duration: 500, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
});

$(".gallery_container").on("mouseleave", function(){    
    $('#color_overlay', this).stop().animate({ opacity:"0" }, {duration: 300, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
    $('#sub_overskrift_container', this).stop().animate({ left: "700px" }, {duration: 300, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
    $('#paragraf_container', this).stop().animate({ left: "-470px" }, {duration: 300, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
    $('#overskrift_container', this).stop().animate({ top: "200px" }, {duration: 700, ease: "easeOutQuint", queue: false});
});
```

Fiddle link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CFx7k/8/

Comment: yes! This helped a lot. I can no longer do the bug. Thank you so much! I've been struggeling with this for a long time :D